# How to travel to O'Hare from Megabus bus stop beside Union Station, Chicago with luggage?

Tags: public-transport, taxis, chicago

I'm flying out of Chicago(O'Hare) on 8th July at a 1:30 PM flight. I reach Union Station, Chicago at 6:45 on the morning of 8th. Other than a backpack, I'll have 2 big luggage pieces(the size for international travel). I want to know- which would be the best route for me to take, to get to O'Hare from the Megabus stop, considering that I have the 2 heavy luggage bags.

1. Without the luggage pieces, I would have picked the Clinton Blue Line train service any day. I've heard it runs all the time, the fare is just $3, and its about just a block or two from the Megabus stop beside Union Station(300m to be exact). But, the problem is my 2 luggage pieces. Will it be a viable option to walk all the way from the Megabus stop to Clinton Blue Line? And not to mention, once I get down at O'Hare from the train, I need to walk to the Airport transport shuttle that will take me to Terminal 5, for international flights.
2. The other option is to take a taxi from the megabus stop. In that case, I'd like to know- how much does it cost normally for a taxi ride all the way to the airport; what is the normal tip you're expected to give; do they accept credit cards in the taxi at Chicago, and any other helpful information you can think of.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nitpicking here, but the fare from O'Hare is now actually $5- the only station with a premium.

Comment: Get rolling luggage. Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

If you can lug your baggage to the Clinton stop of the Blue Line, that will be the easiest option for you. You arrive straight in the airport and can take the elevator right up to the Sky Train, which will take you to Terminal 5. The current Megabus stop is about a block and a half south of Union Station, which makes it even closer to the Clinton Blue Line station. You basically only have to walk 2 blocks (one south and one west) to get to the subway station.

Your other option is to take a cab. It will cost around $40-$50 depending on time of day and company, plus a tip (usually 10-15%). Most major cab companies accept credit cards. You should be able to easily hail a taxi right at the Megabus stop at any time of day.